# Place holder disables the requirements check in contact form 7

Tags: placeholder, contact-form-7

I've been looking for all sorts of solutions and nothing seems to work.

I've tried adding a placeholder tag via a script, I've tried changing the filter number in the php file I've tried disabling all other plugins from the form page.

Nothing worked.

So here's the problem. If I add a placeholder to the input field text it will disable the requirements check on those input fields. As if the placeholder is seen as input.

I have no idea how to fix it. Please help.

You can see the form at https://www.breuerscobelens.nl/offerte/ if you select "Een energielabel voor één adres" and then choose "Woning" you'll see the input fields I've talking about the quickest.

Another thing I'm bumping into is I want the form to automatically go to step two after selection of an option, but even though I've put in place the code I got from the plugin help it still doesn't work.

Any help with this would also be much appreciated.

Code of the form in contact form 7

```html
    
    
    <h5 class="pt-cv-title"><strong>Vraag in drie eenvoudige stappen uw offerte aan</strong></h5>
<br>

[step title "Start" next "volgende stap" previous "vorige stap"]

<h8><strong>Waarvoor ontvangt u graag een offerte?</h8></strong>
[select* stap1-aanvraag first_as_label "Maak uw keuze" "Een energielabel voor één adres" "Energielabels voor meerdere adressen" "Een andere dienst"]

[step title "Enkele vragen voor de scherpste offerte"]

[group energielabel-group]
    <h8><strong>Betreft het een woning of een bedrijfsgebouw?</h8></strong>
    [select* stap2-energielabel-soortgebouw first_as_label "Maak uw keuze" "Woning" "Bedrijfsgebouw" "Combinatie woning/bedrijfsgebouw"]
    <br>

    [group energielabel-woning-group]
        <h8><strong>Wat is het adres van de woning?</strong></h8>
        [text* stap2-energielabel-woning-opname-adres placeholder "Straat en huisnummer*"] 
        [text* stap2-energielabel-woning-opname-postcode placeholder "Postcode*"]
        [text* stap2-energielabel-woning-opname-plaats placeholder "Plaats"]
        <br>
        <h8><strong>Door onderstaande drie vragen te beantwoorden helpt u ons een zo scherp mogelijke offerte te maken!</strong></h8>
        Wat is ongeveer de oppervlakte van de woning?
        [select stap2-energielabel-woning-opname-oppervlakte first_as_label "Ik heb echt geen idee" "<50m²" "50-150m²" "150-300m²" ">500m²"]
        Zijn er bouwtekeningen met maatvoering beschikbaar?
        [select stap2-energielabel-woning-opname-bouwtekeningen first_as_label "Dat weet ik niet" "Jazeker!" "Nee, helaas"]
        Is er ergens in de woning sprake van koeling zoals een airco of een warmtepomp?
        [select stap2-energielabel-woning-opname-koeling first_as_label "Ik heb echt geen idee" "Nee" "Ja" "Ja, maar deze is buiten werking" ]
        <br>
    [/group]

    [group energielabel-bedrijfsgebouw-group]
        <h8><strong>Wat is het adres?</strong></h8>
        [text* stap2-energielabel-bedrijf-opname-adres placeholder "Straat en huisnummer*"]
        [text* stap2-energielabel-bedrijf-opname-postcode placeholder "Postcode*"]
        [text* stap2-energielabel-bedrijf-opname-plaats placeholder "Plaats*"]
        <br>
        <h8><strong>Door onderstaande twee vragen te beantwoorden helpt u ons een zo scherp mogelijke offerte te maken!</strong></h8>
        Wat is ongeveer de oppervlakte, minus een eventuele onverwarmde industriële opslag- of productiehal?
        [select stap2-energielabel-bedrijf-opname-oppervlakte first_as_label "Ik heb echt geen idee" "<100m²" "100-250m²" "250-500m²" "500-1000m²" "1000-2000m²" "2000-3000m²" "3000-5000m²" "5000-7000m²" "7000-10.000m²" ">10.000m²"]
        Zijn er bouwtekeningen met maatvoering beschikbaar?
        [select stap2-energielabel-bedrijf-opname-bouwtekeningen first_as_label "Dat weet ik niet" "Jazeker!" "Nee, helaas"]
        <br>
    [/group]
[/group]

[group energielabels-group]
    Om hoeveel woonadressen gaat het ongeveer? [number stap2-energielabels-aantal-woonadressen min:0 max:100000 "0"]
    Om hoeveel bedrijfsadressen gaat het ongeveer? [number stap2-energiealabels-aantal-bedrijfsadressen min:0 max:10000 "0"]
[/group]

[group anderedienst-group]
    Voor welke dienst wenst u een offerte te ontvangen? [textarea stap2-anderedienst placeholder "Gewenste dienst"]
[/group]

[step title "Tenaamstelling offerte"]
<h8><strong>Tot slot, aan wie mogen we de offerte richten?</strong></h8>
In de hoop dat de offerte naar wens is, zal na oplevering van de werkzaamheden ook de factuur aldus geadresseerd worden.

[select* stap3-offerte-tenaamstelling first_as_label "Maak uw keuze" "Aan een particulier persoon" "Aan een bedrijf of instelling" ]
<br>

[group tenaamstelling-particulier-group]
    [select* stap3-particulier-aanhef first_as_label "Maak uw keuze*" "heer" "mevrouw"]
    [text* stap3-particulier-voorletters placeholder "Voorletters*"]
    [text* stap3-particulier-achternaam placeholder "Achternaam*"]
    [tel* stap3-particulier-telefoonnummer placeholder "Telefoonnummer*"]
    [email* stap3-particulier-e-mail placeholder "E-mail adres*"]
    <br>

    [group energielabel-group]
        Is het offerte adres gelijk aan het adres waar u een energielabel voor aanvraagt?
        [select* stap3-particulier-gelijk-adres "Ja" "Nee" ]
        <br>
    [/group]

    [group particulier-afwijkend-adres-group]
        Wat is het offerte adres?
       [text* stap3-particulier-adres placeholder "Straat en huisnummer*"]
       [text* stap3-particulier-postcode placeholder "Postcode*"]
       [text* stap3-particulier-plaats placeholder "Plaats*"]
        <br>
    [/group]

    [checkbox nieuwsbriefontvangen default:0 "Ik schrijf me graag direct in voor de nieuwsbrief"]
[/group]

[group tenaamstelling-bedrijf-group]
    <h8><strong>Uw gegevens</strong></h8>
    [select* stap3-bedrijf-aanhef first_as_label "Maak uw keuze*" "heer" "mevrouw"]
    [text* stap3-bedrijf-voorletters placeholder "Voorletters*"]
    [text* stap3-bedrijf-achternaam placeholder "Achternaam*"]
    [tel* stap3-bedrijf-telefoonnummer placeholder "Telefoonnummer*"]
    [email* stap3-bedrijf-e-mail placeholder "E-mail adres*"]
    <br>

    <h8><strong>Bedrijfsgegevens</strong></h8>
    [text* stap3-bedrijf-bedrijfsnaam placeholder "Bedrijfsnaam*"] 
    [text stap3-bedrijf-kvk placeholder "KvK nr"]
    [text stap3-bedrijf-e-mail-facturatie placeholder "Optioneel afwijkend e-mailadres alleen voor factuur"]
    [group energielabel-group]
        Is het bedrijfsadres gelijk aan het adres waar u een energielabel voor aanvraagt?
        [select* stap3-bedrijf-gelijk-adres "Ja" "Nee" ]
        <br>
    [/group]

    [group bedrijf-afwijkend-adres-group]
        <h8><strong>Wat is het bedrijfsadres voor de offerte tenaamstelling?</h8></strong>
        [text* stap3-bedrijf-adres placeholder "Straat en huisnummer*"]
        [text* stap3-bedrijf-postcode placeholder "Postcode*"]
        [text* stap3-bedrijf-plaats placeholder "Plaats*"]
        <br>
    [/group]

    [checkbox nieuwsbriefontvangen default:1 "Nieuwsbrief ontvangen"]
[/group]
[submit "Verstuur mijn aanvraag!"]
[group particulier-gelijk-adres-group][/group]
[group bedrijf-gelijk-adres-group][/group]
```

```
Requirement field error code.
```

```html
<?php
/**
** A base module for the following types of tags:
**  [text] and [text*]      # Single-line text
**  [email] and [email*]    # Email address
**  [url] and [url*]        # URL
**  [tel] and [tel*]        # Telephone number
**/

/* form_tag handler */

add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_text', 10, 0 );

function wpcf7_add_form_tag_text() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag(
        array( 'text', 'text*', 'email', 'email*', 'url', 'url*', 'tel', 'tel*' ),
        'wpcf7_text_form_tag_handler',
        array(
            'name-attr' => true,
        )
    );
}

function wpcf7_text_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
    if ( empty( $tag->name ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $validation_error = wpcf7_get_validation_error( $tag->name );

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type, 'wpcf7-text' );

    if ( in_array( $tag->basetype, array( 'email', 'url', 'tel' ) ) ) {
        $class .= ' wpcf7-validates-as-' . $tag->basetype;
    }

    if ( $validation_error ) {
        $class .= ' wpcf7-not-valid';
    }

    $atts = array();

    $atts['size'] = $tag->get_size_option( '40' );
    $atts['maxlength'] = $tag->get_maxlength_option();
    $atts['minlength'] = $tag->get_minlength_option();

    if ( $atts['maxlength'] and $atts['minlength']
    and $atts['maxlength'] < $atts['minlength'] ) {
        unset( $atts['maxlength'], $atts['minlength'] );
    }

    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'signed_int', true );

    $atts['autocomplete'] = $tag->get_option( 'autocomplete',
        '[-0-9a-zA-Z]+', true );

    if ( $tag->has_option( 'readonly' ) ) {
        $atts['readonly'] = 'readonly';
    }

    if ( $tag->is_required() ) {
        $atts['aria-required'] = 'true';
    }

    if ( $validation_error ) {
        $atts['aria-invalid'] = 'true';
        $atts['aria-describedby'] = wpcf7_get_validation_error_reference(
            $tag->name
        );
    } else {
        $atts['aria-invalid'] = 'false';
    }

    $value = (string) reset( $tag->values );

    if ( $tag->has_option( 'placeholder' )
    or $tag->has_option( 'watermark' ) ) {
        $atts['placeholder'] = $value;
        $value = '';
    }

    $value = $tag->get_default_option( $value );

    $value = wpcf7_get_hangover( $tag->name, $value );

    $atts['value'] = $value;

    if ( wpcf7_support_html5() ) {
        $atts['type'] = $tag->basetype;
    } else {
        $atts['type'] = 'text';
    }

    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;

    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

    $html = sprintf(
        '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><input %2$s />%3$s</span>',
        sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $atts, $validation_error
    );

    return $html;
}


/* Validation filter */

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'wpcf7_text_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'wpcf7_text_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email', 'wpcf7_text_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'wpcf7_text_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_url', 'wpcf7_text_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_url*', 'wpcf7_text_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_tel', 'wpcf7_text_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_tel*', 'wpcf7_text_validation_filter', 10, 2 );

function wpcf7_text_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    $name = $tag->name;

    $value = isset( $_POST[$name] )
        ? trim( wp_unslash( strtr( (string) $_POST[$name], "\n", " " ) ) )
        : '';

    if ( 'text' == $tag->basetype ) {
        if ( $tag->is_required() and '' === $value ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
        }
    }

    if ( 'email' == $tag->basetype ) {
        if ( $tag->is_required() and '' === $value ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
        } elseif ( '' !== $value and ! wpcf7_is_email( $value ) ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_email' ) );
        }
    }

    if ( 'url' == $tag->basetype ) {
        if ( $tag->is_required() and '' === $value ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
        } elseif ( '' !== $value and ! wpcf7_is_url( $value ) ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_url' ) );
        }
    }

    if ( 'tel' == $tag->basetype ) {
        if ( $tag->is_required() and '' === $value ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
        } elseif ( '' !== $value and ! wpcf7_is_tel( $value ) ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_tel' ) );
        }
    }

    if ( '' !== $value ) {
        $maxlength = $tag->get_maxlength_option();
        $minlength = $tag->get_minlength_option();

        if ( $maxlength and $minlength and $maxlength < $minlength ) {
            $maxlength = $minlength = null;
        }

        $code_units = wpcf7_count_code_units( stripslashes( $value ) );

        if ( false !== $code_units ) {
            if ( $maxlength and $maxlength < $code_units ) {
                $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_too_long' ) );
            } elseif ( $minlength and $code_units < $minlength ) {
                $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_too_short' ) );
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}


/* Messages */

add_filter( 'wpcf7_messages', 'wpcf7_text_messages', 10, 1 );

function wpcf7_text_messages( $messages ) {
    $messages = array_merge( $messages, array(
        'invalid_email' => array(
            'description' =>
                __( "Email address that the sender entered is invalid", 'contact-form-7' ),
            'default' =>
                __( "The e-mail address entered is invalid.", 'contact-form-7' ),
        ),

        'invalid_url' => array(
            'description' =>
                __( "URL that the sender entered is invalid", 'contact-form-7' ),
            'default' =>
                __( "The URL is invalid.", 'contact-form-7' ),
        ),

        'invalid_tel' => array(
            'description' =>
                __( "Telephone number that the sender entered is invalid", 'contact-form-7' ),
            'default' =>
                __( "The telephone number is invalid.", 'contact-form-7' ),
        ),
    ) );

    return $messages;
}


/* Tag generator */

add_action( 'wpcf7_admin_init', 'wpcf7_add_tag_generator_text', 15, 0 );

function wpcf7_add_tag_generator_text() {
    $tag_generator = WPCF7_TagGenerator::get_instance();
    $tag_generator->add( 'text', __( 'text', 'contact-form-7' ),
        'wpcf7_tag_generator_text' );
    $tag_generator->add( 'email', __( 'email', 'contact-form-7' ),
        'wpcf7_tag_generator_text' );
    $tag_generator->add( 'url', __( 'URL', 'contact-form-7' ),
        'wpcf7_tag_generator_text' );
    $tag_generator->add( 'tel', __( 'tel', 'contact-form-7' ),
        'wpcf7_tag_generator_text' );
}

function wpcf7_tag_generator_text( $contact_form, $args = '' ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array() );
    $type = $args['id'];

    if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'email', 'url', 'tel' ) ) ) {
        $type = 'text';
    }

    if ( 'text' == $type ) {
        $description = __( "Generate a form-tag for a single-line plain text input field. For more details, see %s.", 'contact-form-7' );
    } elseif ( 'email' == $type ) {
        $description = __( "Generate a form-tag for a single-line email address input field. For more details, see %s.", 'contact-form-7' );
    } elseif ( 'url' == $type ) {
        $description = __( "Generate a form-tag for a single-line URL input field. For more details, see %s.", 'contact-form-7' );
    } elseif ( 'tel' == $type ) {
        $description = __( "Generate a form-tag for a single-line telephone number input field. For more details, see %s.", 'contact-form-7' );
    }

    $desc_link = wpcf7_link( __( 'https://contactform7.com/text-fields/', 'contact-form-7' ), __( 'Text fields', 'contact-form-7' ) );

?>
<div class="control-box">
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo sprintf( esc_html( $description ), $desc_link ); ?></legend>

<table class="form-table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Field type', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></th>
    <td>
        <fieldset>
        <legend class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Field type', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></legend>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="required" /> <?php echo esc_html( __( 'Required field', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></label>
        </fieldset>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-name' ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Name', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" class="tg-name oneline" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-name' ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-values' ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Default value', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="values" class="oneline" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-values' ); ?>" /><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="placeholder" class="option" /> <?php echo esc_html( __( 'Use this text as the placeholder of the field', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></label></td>
    </tr>

<?php if ( in_array( $type, array( 'text', 'email', 'url' ) ) ) : ?>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Akismet', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></th>
    <td>
        <fieldset>
        <legend class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Akismet', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></legend>

<?php if ( 'text' == $type ) : ?>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="akismet:author" class="option" />
            <?php echo esc_html( __( "This field requires author's name", 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?>
        </label>
<?php elseif ( 'email' == $type ) : ?>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="akismet:author_email" class="option" />
            <?php echo esc_html( __( "This field requires author's email address", 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?>
        </label>
<?php elseif ( 'url' == $type ) : ?>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="akismet:author_url" class="option" />
            <?php echo esc_html( __( "This field requires author's URL", 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?>
        </label>
<?php endif; ?>

        </fieldset>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-id' ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Id attribute', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="id" class="idvalue oneline option" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-id' ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-class' ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Class attribute', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?></label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="class" class="classvalue oneline option" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-class' ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
</div>

<div class="insert-box">
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $type; ?>" class="tag code" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.select()" />

    <div class="submitbox">
    <input type="button" class="button button-primary insert-tag" value="<?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Insert Tag', 'contact-form-7' ) ); ?>" />
    </div>

    <br class="clear" />

    <p class="description mail-tag"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-mailtag' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf( esc_html( __( "To use the value input through this field in a mail field, you need to insert the corresponding mail-tag (%s) into the field on the Mail tab.", 'contact-form-7' ) ), '<strong><span class="mail-tag"></span></strong>' ); ?><input type="text" class="mail-tag code hidden" readonly="readonly" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['content'] . '-mailtag' ); ?>" /></label></p>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Code to go to next step automatically

```js
    /**
     * Validate the current step, and move to step number `step` if validation passes.
     * @memberof wpcf7cf
     * @param {String|JQuery} $form - JQuery object or css-selector representing the form
     * @param {Number} step 
     */
    async multistepMoveToStepWithValidation(3925, 1) {
        const multistep = wpcf7cf.getMultiStepObj(3925);

        var result = await multistep.validateStep(multistep.currentStep);
        if (result === 'success') {
            multistep.moveToStep(2); 
        }
    },


};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue.

In the theme there was a function for the sitesearch. It said that if the field was empty the placeholder should be send in as input. Insane. So I disabled that piece of code and now it's working perfectly.